# SharePoint 2013 - New Web Application creation

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to create new web application but after sometimes it prompts request timed out. I tried again after setting the application pool defaults to 400, then with powershell but no luck.

I checked with the ULS viewer as well and correlation id is not found in that.

Please let me know what I'm missing here, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set higher value at IIS and i recommend you to increase RAM at Web server.

The web application created through Power-Shell means the SharePoint side is working fine.

It looks like short of resources is the issue.

Comment: @Krunal Rohit ,please upvote and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: This doesn't help, have already tried this. RAM is 16gb on server, IIS limit is 900. Can you please help me with the spfarm user permissions ?